# Rotation matrix given angle and axis, properties

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a single normal vector, say $\vec{n}$ and I like to construct an orthonormal basis given this vector, and $\vec{n}$ must be an element of the basis.

Among the possibilities I was thinking of this specific one. I can look at $\vec{n}$ as a rotation axis, and defining $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$, I can the construct a rotation matrix by using the formula

$$
R = I + \left[\vec{n}\right]_{\times} \sin(\theta) + \left[\vec{n}\right]_{\times}^2 \left(1 - \cos(\theta) \right)
$$

Clearly the rotation matrix rows form an orthonormal basis, now if one of these rows is the original $\vec{n}$ my problem is essentially solved.

Whether or not this is the most efficient way is a bit irrelevant, but I'm more curious if the procedure I'm describing works.

But I'm not 100% this procedure is actually correct.

Can you confirm?

To me this should be correct, because if $V = span\left\{ \vec{n} \right\}$ such space will be the eigen space of the operator $R$, and it should also rotate any element of the orthogonal complement of $V$.

Comment: "now if one of these rows my problem is essentially solved": ???

Comment: My apologies, I meant if one of the rows (or columns) were $\vec{n}$

Answer (score 1):

As $R$ is a rotation around $\vec n$ and the rows are the images of the canonical axis, you can be sure that no row is ever $\vec n$.

---

I assume that $\vec n$ is unit. Take an arbitrary vector not parallel to $\vec n$, let $\vec z$, and set

$$\vec m:=\frac{\vec z\times\vec n}{\|\vec z\times\vec n\|}.$$

Then
$$(\vec n,\vec m,\vec n\times\vec m)$$ forms an orthonormal basis.

Comment: I was aware of this procedure, but as I mentioned I was curious about the approach I was suggesting. Also I cannot take $\vec{z}$ arbitrary, it has to belong to the orthogonal complement of $span\left\{ \vec{n} \right\}$, the dual plane.

Comment: @user8469759: 1) you didn't say that; 2) I refuted your method an suggested one that works.

Comment: I didn't say the constraint of the dual plane, not explicitly at least (sorry). Could you suggest a way to get a vector in the dual plane? I'd suppose I might use the rejection of the arbitrary vector..